# spring boot2.1 cannot switch redis databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

my properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/apitest
spring.jackson.time-zone=GMT+8
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.database=1
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.session.store-type=redis
```

my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

when i run my application, i find my redis database always is 0, how to switch to 1?

Comment: how can you know that your redis database is 0, from log?

Comment: from my redis database @clevertension

Comment: can you paste the code and give your verification steps?